# Pygame object on sprite not showing

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I have a little problem when trying to learn about sprites in Pygame.

To begin with, i have already put a great amount of effort into this with sprites but i dont get it to work.

I have done exactly what guides on the internet are showing when drawing an object onto a sprite but object doesnt show up while running program.

Any suggestions would be more than welcome!

```
tick = 0
sprite = pygame.Surface([20, 20])
sprite.fill(white)
sprite.set_colorkey(white)
rect = sprite.get_rect()
rect.x = 400
rect.y = 300


while tick < 100:

    screen.fill(black)

    pygame.draw.rect(sprite, red, [rect.x, rect.y, 20, 20])
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(10)
    tick += 1


pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: You're filling the surface with white and then setting the colorkey of white. Remove the colorkey and it should work. Short about colorkeys [here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/pygame/7079/drawing-on-the-screen/23788/transparency#t=201704140013573679697)

Comment: it is more wrong than that.

Answer (score 1):

So, there are two major problems with your code. 
First, you are filling the surface you are calling sprite with "white" and then just setting "white" to be treated as a transparent color for that surface, with the call to `set_colorkey`. So, nothing could show up anyway.

Second, you are drawing your rectangle on the Surface itself, not on your screen. So, you do suceed in painting it red, but you don't "stamp" it on the screen - you call `pygame.draw.rect` to draw on the Surface you are calling sprite itself, not on the screen.

Your code does not show you declaring a screen at all - I suppose you did that correctly, nonetheless keep in mind you always should post a complete example that will get the behavior you get there. If there is an error in your code to set up the screen, I can't know about it. Also, I've changed our call to `draw.rect` to call `screen.blit` : that will stamp whatever image is currently on the sprite on the surface owner of the blit method - in this case, the screen itself:

```
import pygame
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
white = 255, 255, 255
tick = 0
sprite = pygame.Surface([20, 20])
sprite.fill(white)
sprite.set_colorkey(white)
rect = sprite.get_rect()
rect.x = 400
rect.y = 300


while tick < 100:

    screen.fill(black)
    screen.blit(sprite, (rect.x, rect.y))

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(10)
    tick += 1

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

With that you should see a white rectangle shortly  - from them on you can start improving your code to delay the program ending, or wait an user event to close the screen and get things rolling.

By the way, in Pygame talk, a Surface is not quite considered a "sprite" - a `Sprite` is a special class meant to be used as members of "groups" upon which a series of helper functions will work when you start organizing a more complete game or animated sequence.

Answer (score 1):

[Pygame documents](http://pygame.org/docs/) is a good friend.

1.Why would you fill `sprite` white and then set its color key to white? This will just make the sprite transparent. See [set_colorkey](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.set_colorkey).

```
sprite = pygame.Surface([20, 20])
sprite.fill(white)
sprite.set_colorkey(white)
```

If you need a red `sprite`, just create one and fill it red.

```
sprite = pygame.Surface((20, 20))
sprite.fill(red)
```

2.What [`pygame.draw.rect`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.rect) do is just drawing a rectangular shape on the `Surface`. So if you want to draw a red rect on the screen, just

```
pygame.draw.rect(screen, red, (0, 0, 20, 20))
```

Or if you want to show the sprite on the screen, which is usually more effective, use [`blit`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit)

```
screen.blit(sprite, (0, 0))
```

Have fun with pygame :)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to start doing some programming with Pygame directly using sprites, it would be a good idea to do some more preliminary study of available tutorials to get some basic understanding how applications using GUIs and capable of handling user events work in general.

Another option is to start with easier things where it is possible to see the result directly without the need of writing the necessary (sprites need Groups and a class) voluminous preliminary code.

There are beside a huge amount of hard to understand tutorials on Pygame sprites also some which provide nice examples of code and quite good explanations.  I suggest you take a closer look at:

> [Introduction to sprites](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=introduction_to_sprites)  ---  [sprite_collect_blocks.py](http://programarcadegames.com/python_examples/f.php?file=sprite_collect_blocks.py)

and then come back here with further questions, if any.

Below I have provided two pieces of code, so that you can compare them to each other to see what I have been speaking above about.

The first piece of the two is your own code with slight modifications. It creates three blocks on the screen and what it actually does has nothing to do with sprites (as it is also the case in the another answer), but shows how to populate the displayed Pygame screen with rectangles. Read carefully also the another answers as they provide good explanations of the issues your own code comes with.

```
import pygame

WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
RED   = (255,0,0)
BLUE  = (0,0,255)

# Set the height and width of the screen:
DISPLAY_width  = 640
DISPLAY_height = 480
DISPLAY = pygame.display.set_mode([DISPLAY_width, DISPLAY_height])
DISPLAY.fill(WHITE)

# See here:  [(3) stackoverflow.com/.../pygame-drawing-a-rectangle][3] 
pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAY,BLACK,(120,40,50,50))
pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAY,RED  ,(520,355,50,50))
pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAY,BLUE ,(320,240,50,50))
pygame.display.flip() # without .flip() you get only black screen

pygame.display.init() # IMPORTANT !

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
tick = 0
while tick < 100:
    clock.tick(10)
    tick += 1

# BETTER do it as follows: 
"""
done = False
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get(): 
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            done = True
"""

pygame.quit()
import sys
sys.exit()
```

Here a screenshot of what the code above creates:

[image: Pygame window the code above creates]

The other piece of code is actual code using sprites. Sprites are usually used together with images. This makes it necessary to get some images in the scripts directory first:

[image: red dot] [image: purple dot] [image: orange dot] [image: grey dot] [image: blue dot]
[image]

And here goes the second piece of code (with TRUE sprites) which produces much MOTION on the screen (here only a static screenshot). All of the dots are in movement with different speeds filling the initially black screen with yellow color:

[image]

```
strPythonScriptHeader = """
# pygCodeSample_UsageOfGroupsAndSprites.py             updated: 2017-04-12 09:17
# Copyright (c) 2005,  Claudio at stackoverflow.com    created: 2005-01-24 19:43
"""
# #############################################################################
# VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV
def pygCodeSample_UsageOfGroupsAndSprites(): 
  strMainInfo = """/*
    WATCH OUT using pygame.sprite.Sprite and pygame.sprite.RenderClear classes: 
    - the order of Sprites in a Group is not necessary the order in which the 
        Sprites are drawn to the screen.
    - the .clear() method of a Group clears the entire image square, not as 
        expected only the non-transparent part of it.
  */"""
  print( strMainInfo )
  strSpriteTutorial = """/*
    The 'pygame.sprite' library provides classes representing images and 
    group of images which are to be drawn to the screen during the game. 
    The concept of a 'Sprite' is to provide a class which objects represent 
    real-world physical objects which can be viewed on the computer screen. 
    The Sprite class is not used directly. It is used to derive own classes 
    of customized Sprites from it: 
      class CustomizedSpriteDerivedFromSpriteClass(pygame.sprite.Sprite): ... 
    Within the definition of the CustomizedSpriteDerivedFromSpriteClass 
    it is necessary to define a member variable 
      .image       (class CustomizedSpriteDerivedFromSpriteClass)
    storing an 'Image' object which is to draw to the screen and the 
    member variable 
      .rect        (class CustomizedSpriteDerivedFromSpriteClass)
    storing a 'Rect' object holding the target position of the 'Image' 
    on the screen. 
    Usually both variables are set when running the 
      .__init__()  (class CustomizedSpriteDerivedFromSpriteClass)
    function which should contain as first command: 
      pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__( self )
    Further is it necessary to define also an 
      .update()    (class CustomizedSpriteDerivedFromSpriteClass)
    function which provides the code of rules telling how the by the Sprite 
    graphically represented physical objects should change when the .update() 
    function is executed. 
    The main purpose of a 'Sprite' is to be added to a container(called Group) 
    which is an object of the pygame.sprite.RenderClear class: 
      pGobjGroupOfSprites = pygame.sprite.RenderClear()
    ready to hold any number of Sprite objects. A single Sprite is added to it
    using 
      pGobjGroupOfSprites.add(pGobjCustomizedSpriteDerivedFromSpriteClass)
    call. 
    The pGobjGroupOfSprites object of the pygame.sprite.RenderClear class is 
    equipped with following methods: 
      pGobjGroupOfSprites.clear(pGobjSCREENsurface, pGobjImage_SCREENsurfaceBackground)
      pGobjGroupOfSprites.update() 
      pGobjGroupOfSprites.draw( pGobjSCREENsurface)
    .draw()  draws all Sprites to as parameter passed pGobjSCREENsurface
      using the .image and .rect properties defined as member variables 
      within the CustomizedSpriteDerivedFromSpriteClass class. 
    .clear() draws those parts of the pGobjImage_SCREENsurfaceBackground image 
      to the pGobjSCREENsurface which are the Rects representing the 
      positions of the Sprites on the screen using the .rect property of Sprites.
    .update() runs the .update() method of each Sprite stored in the GroupOfSprites. 
    Finally the main game loop looks like: 

      while True: 
        evaluateInputEvents()

        pGobjGroupOfSprites_Hero.clear(pGobjSCREENsurface, pGobjImage_SCREENsurfaceBackground)
        pGobjGroupOfSprites_Hero.update() 
        pGobjGroupOfSprites_Hero.draw( pGobjSCREENsurface)

        pGobjGroupOfSprites_Enemy.clear(pGobjSCREENsurface, pGobjImage_SCREENsurfaceBackground)
        pGobjGroupOfSprites_Enemy.update() 
        pGobjGroupOfSprites_Enemy.draw( pGobjSCREENsurface)

        pGobjGroupOfSprites_Widgets.clear(pGobjSCREENsurface, pGobjImage_SCREENsurfaceBackground)
        pGobjGroupOfSprites_Widgets.update() 
        pGobjGroupOfSprites_Widgets.draw( pGobjSCREENsurface)

        adjustFrameRateTo(intTargetFrameRate) # time.sleep()/time.clock()

        pGdefUpdateScreenWithDataStoredIn_pGobjSCREENsurface  # == pygame.display.flip
      #:while  

    How many and which Groups should be used and how to spread all the Sprites 
    used in the game over the defined Groups is part of the architecture of 
    the game code which is designed according to the needs of the game and the 
    individual programming style. 
  */"""
  print( strSpriteTutorial )

  mPGvDctRectOfSCREENsurface = { 'left' : 0, 'right' : 640, 'top' : 0, 'bottom' : 480 }
  mPGvIntScreenOriginX = mPGvDctRectOfSCREENsurface['left']
  mPGvIntScreenOriginY = mPGvDctRectOfSCREENsurface['top']
  mPGvIntScreenWidth   = mPGvDctRectOfSCREENsurface['right']  - mPGvDctRectOfSCREENsurface['left']
  mPGvIntScreenHeight  = mPGvDctRectOfSCREENsurface['bottom'] - mPGvDctRectOfSCREENsurface['top']
  mPGvTplScreenSize    = (mPGvIntScreenWidth, mPGvIntScreenHeight)

  import pygame
  pGdefUpdateScreenWithDataStoredIn_pGobjSCREENsurface = pygame.display.flip

  class pGobjCustomizedSprite_Dot( pygame.sprite.Sprite ):

    def __init__( self, strColorOfDot, tplVelocity ):
      # Intialize the Sprite class: 
      pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__( self )

      # .image property is used by the pGobjGroup hosting the sprite, so it is 
      # necessary to set it here in order to make this Sprite useful: 
      self.image = pygame.image.load(
          r'dot-32x32_'+strColorOfDot+'.gif'
      ) # picture shows a coloured dot and has a transparent background

      # .rect property is used by the pGobjGroup hosting the sprite, so it is 
      # necessary to set it here in order to make this Sprite useful: 
      self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
      self.rect.centerx = 320
      self.rect.centery = 240

      # definition of other properties not necessary for usage of this class 
      # as a Sprite, but useful for internal purposes of setting the position 
      # of the rectangle within the .update() method: 
      self.x_velocity = tplVelocity[0]
      self.y_velocity = tplVelocity[1]
    #:def

    # .update() method is used by the pGobjGroup hosting the sprite in its 
    # .update() command, so it is necessary to define it here in order to 
    # make this Sprite useful: 
    def update( self ):
      self.rect.move_ip( (self.x_velocity, self.y_velocity) )
      if(self.rect.left <= 0 or self.rect.right >= mPGvIntScreenWidth):
          self.x_velocity = -(self.x_velocity)
      #:if
      if self.rect.top <= 0 or self.rect.bottom >= mPGvIntScreenHeight:
          self.y_velocity = -(self.y_velocity)
      #:if
    #:def
  #:class

  pygame.init()

  # pGobjSCREENsurface = pygame.display.set_mode(mPGvTplScreenSize, pygame.constants.DOUBLEBUF)
  pGobjSCREENsurface = pygame.display.set_mode(mPGvTplScreenSize) # faster than with DOUBLEBUF

  pGobjGroupOfSprites_spriteDot = pygame.sprite.RenderClear()
  pGobjImage_SCREENsurfaceBackground  = pygame.image.load(
    r'rect-640x480_yellow.bmp'
  ) # picture shows yellow background

  intLstLength = 0
  dctTplVelocity = {}
  import random
  while(intLstLength < 5):
    tplVelocity = (random.randint( 1, 5 ), random.randint( 1, 5 ))
    if(tplVelocity in dctTplVelocity): pass
    else: 
      intLstLength+=1
      dctTplVelocity[tplVelocity] = intLstLength
    #:if/else
  #:while
  lstTplVelocity = list(dctTplVelocity.keys())
  # pGspriteRedDot    = pGobjCustomizedSprite_Dot('red'   ,lstTplVelocity[0])
  # pGspriteWhiteDot  = pGobjCustomizedSprite_Dot('purple',lstTplVelocity[1])
  # pGspriteGreyDot   = pGobjCustomizedSprite_Dot('grey'  ,lstTplVelocity[2])
  # pGspriteBlueDot   = pGobjCustomizedSprite_Dot('blue'  ,lstTplVelocity[3])
  # pGspriteOrangeDot = pGobjCustomizedSprite_Dot('orange',lstTplVelocity[4])
  pGobjGroupOfSprites_spriteDot.add(pGobjCustomizedSprite_Dot('red'   ,lstTplVelocity[0]))
  pGobjGroupOfSprites_spriteDot.add(pGobjCustomizedSprite_Dot('purple',lstTplVelocity[1]))
  pGobjGroupOfSprites_spriteDot.add(pGobjCustomizedSprite_Dot('grey'  ,lstTplVelocity[2]))
  pGobjGroupOfSprites_spriteDot.add(pGobjCustomizedSprite_Dot('blue'  ,lstTplVelocity[3]))
  pGobjGroupOfSprites_spriteDot.add(pGobjCustomizedSprite_Dot('orange',lstTplVelocity[4]))

  print 
  print( '  target frame rate [frames/second] == 100.0 : ' )
  intLoopCounter = 0

  import time
  clock = time.clock
  sleep = time.sleep
  import sys

  fltTime=clock()
  fltStartTime = clock()

  blnExitMainGameLoop = False

  fltFrameRate       = 100.0
  fltTimeToNextFrame = 1.0 / fltFrameRate
  import time
  while True:
    time.sleep(0.03)
    # --- 
    # -----------------------------------------------------
    # Processing of user input: 
    pGlstObjEvent = pygame.event.get()
    for pGobjEvent in pGlstObjEvent:
      if pGobjEvent.type == pygame.constants.QUIT: 
        blnExitMainGameLoop = True
      #:if
      if pGobjEvent.type == pygame.constants.KEYDOWN:
        if pGobjEvent.key == pygame.constants.K_ESCAPE: 
          blnExitMainGameLoop = True
        if pGobjEvent.key == pygame.constants.K_s: 
          time.sleep(21)
          blnExitMainGameLoop = False
        #:if
      #:if
    #:for
    if(blnExitMainGameLoop): 
      pygame.display.quit()
      break
    #:if

    # --- 
    # -----------------------------------------------------
    # output of texts with infos to console window: 
    if(intLoopCounter%100 == 99):
      print( ' %5.2f '%(fltFrameRate/(clock()-fltTime),), )
      fltTime=clock()
    #:if
    intLoopCounter += 1
    # print intLoopCounter,

    # --- 
    # -----------------------------------------------------
    # preparing and drawing graphic output to screen: 
    pGobjGroupOfSprites_spriteDot.update()
    pGobjGroupOfSprites_spriteDot.clear(pGobjSCREENsurface, pGobjImage_SCREENsurfaceBackground)
    pGobjGroupOfSprites_spriteDot.draw( pGobjSCREENsurface)

    # --- 
    # -----------------------------------------------------
    # adjusting frame rate to 100 frames/second: 
    # fltFrameRate       = 100.0
    # fltTimeToNextFrame = 1.0 / fltFrameRate
    fltTargetTime = fltTimeToNextFrame*intLoopCounter
    fltTimeDiff = fltTargetTime-(clock()-fltStartTime)
    if(fltTimeDiff > 0.8*fltTimeToNextFrame): sleep(0.8*fltTimeToNextFrame)
    fltTimeDiff = fltTargetTime-(clock()-fltStartTime)
    if(fltTimeDiff > 0.1*fltTimeToNextFrame): sleep(0.1*fltTimeToNextFrame)
    fltTimeDiff = fltTargetTime-(clock()-fltStartTime)
    while(fltTimeDiff > 0):
      fltTimeDiff = (fltTimeToNextFrame*intLoopCounter)-(clock()-fltStartTime)
    #:while

    # --- 
    # -----------------------------------------------------
    # displaying prepared graphic output: 
    pGdefUpdateScreenWithDataStoredIn_pGobjSCREENsurface()

  #:while
#:def pygCodeSample_UsageOfGroupsAndSprites()
# ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

if __name__ == '__main__': 
  print( strPythonScriptHeader )
  pygCodeSample_UsageOfGroupsAndSprites()
  import sys
  if int(sys.version[0]) < 3 :   # Python 2 :
      raw_input('(exit with ENTER) #> OK? ')
      sys.exit()
  else:                          # Python 3 : 
      input('(exit with ENTER) #> OK? ')
      sys.exit()
#:if
pygameConstantsForUsageInKeyEVENTS = ['ACTIVEEVENT', 'ANYFORMAT', 'ASYNCBLIT', 'AUDIO_S16', 'AUDIO_S16LSB', 'AUDIO_S16MSB', 'AUDIO_S16SYS', 'AUDIO_S8', 'AUDIO_U16', 'AUDIO_U16LSB', 'AUDIO_U16MSB', 'AUDIO_U16SYS', 'AUDIO_U8', 'BIG_ENDIAN', 'BLEND_ADD', 'BLEND_MAX', 'BLEND_MIN', 'BLEND_MULT', 'BLEND_PREMULTIPLIED', 'BLEND_RGBA_ADD', 'BLEND_RGBA_MAX', 'BLEND_RGBA_MIN', 'BLEND_RGBA_MULT', 'BLEND_RGBA_SUB', 'BLEND_RGB_ADD', 'BLEND_RGB_MAX', 'BLEND_RGB_MIN', 'BLEND_RGB_MULT', 'BLEND_RGB_SUB', 'BLEND_SUB', 'BUTTON_X1', 'BUTTON_X2', 'DOUBLEBUF', 'FULLSCREEN', 'GL_ACCELERATED_VISUAL', 'GL_ACCUM_ALPHA_SIZE', 'GL_ACCUM_BLUE_SIZE', 'GL_ACCUM_GREEN_SIZE', 'GL_ACCUM_RED_SIZE', 'GL_ALPHA_SIZE', 'GL_BLUE_SIZE', 'GL_BUFFER_SIZE', 'GL_DEPTH_SIZE', 'GL_DOUBLEBUFFER', 'GL_GREEN_SIZE', 'GL_MULTISAMPLEBUFFERS', 'GL_MULTISAMPLESAMPLES', 'GL_RED_SIZE', 'GL_STENCIL_SIZE', 'GL_STEREO', 'GL_SWAP_CONTROL', 'HAT_CENTERED', 'HAT_DOWN', 'HAT_LEFT', 'HAT_LEFTDOWN', 'HAT_LEFTUP', 'HAT_RIGHT', 'HAT_RIGHTDOWN', 'HAT_RIGHTUP', 'HAT_UP', 'HWACCEL', 'HWPALETTE', 'HWSURFACE', 'IYUV_OVERLAY', 'JOYAXISMOTION', 'JOYBALLMOTION', 'JOYBUTTONDOWN', 'JOYBUTTONUP', 'JOYHATMOTION', 'KEYDOWN', 'KEYUP', 'KMOD_ALT', 'KMOD_CAPS', 'KMOD_CTRL', 'KMOD_LALT', 'KMOD_LCTRL', 'KMOD_LMETA', 'KMOD_LSHIFT', 'KMOD_META', 'KMOD_MODE', 'KMOD_NONE', 'KMOD_NUM', 'KMOD_RALT', 'KMOD_RCTRL', 'KMOD_RMETA', 'KMOD_RSHIFT', 'KMOD_SHIFT', 'K_0', 'K_1', 'K_2', 'K_3', 'K_4', 'K_5', 'K_6', 'K_7', 'K_8', 'K_9', 'K_AMPERSAND', 'K_ASTERISK', 'K_AT', 'K_BACKQUOTE', 'K_BACKSLASH', 'K_BACKSPACE', 'K_BREAK', 'K_CAPSLOCK', 'K_CARET', 'K_CLEAR', 'K_COLON', 'K_COMMA', 'K_DELETE', 'K_DOLLAR', 'K_DOWN', 'K_END', 'K_EQUALS', 'K_ESCAPE', 'K_EURO', 'K_EXCLAIM', 'K_F1', 'K_F10', 'K_F11', 'K_F12', 'K_F13', 'K_F14', 'K_F15', 'K_F2', 'K_F3', 'K_F4', 'K_F5', 'K_F6', 'K_F7', 'K_F8', 'K_F9', 'K_FIRST', 'K_GREATER', 'K_HASH', 'K_HELP', 'K_HOME', 'K_INSERT', 'K_KP0', 'K_KP1', 'K_KP2', 'K_KP3', 'K_KP4', 'K_KP5', 'K_KP6', 'K_KP7', 'K_KP8', 'K_KP9', 'K_KP_DIVIDE', 'K_KP_ENTER', 'K_KP_EQUALS', 'K_KP_MINUS', 'K_KP_MULTIPLY', 'K_KP_PERIOD', 'K_KP_PLUS', 'K_LALT', 'K_LAST', 'K_LCTRL', 'K_LEFT', 'K_LEFTBRACKET', 'K_LEFTPAREN', 'K_LESS', 'K_LMETA', 'K_LSHIFT', 'K_LSUPER', 'K_MENU', 'K_MINUS', 'K_MODE', 'K_NUMLOCK', 'K_PAGEDOWN', 'K_PAGEUP', 'K_PAUSE', 'K_PERIOD', 'K_PLUS', 'K_POWER', 'K_PRINT', 'K_QUESTION', 'K_QUOTE', 'K_QUOTEDBL', 'K_RALT', 'K_RCTRL', 'K_RETURN', 'K_RIGHT', 'K_RIGHTBRACKET', 'K_RIGHTPAREN', 'K_RMETA', 'K_RSHIFT', 'K_RSUPER', 'K_SCROLLOCK', 'K_SEMICOLON', 'K_SLASH', 'K_SPACE', 'K_SYSREQ', 'K_TAB', 'K_UNDERSCORE', 'K_UNKNOWN', 'K_UP', 'K_a', 'K_b', 'K_c', 'K_d', 'K_e', 'K_f', 'K_g', 'K_h', 'K_i', 'K_j', 'K_k', 'K_l', 'K_m', 'K_n', 'K_o', 'K_p', 'K_q', 'K_r', 'K_s', 'K_t', 'K_u', 'K_v', 'K_w', 'K_x', 'K_y', 'K_z', 'LIL_ENDIAN', 'MOUSEBUTTONDOWN', 'MOUSEBUTTONUP', 'MOUSEMOTION', 'NOEVENT', 'NOFRAME', 'NUMEVENTS', 'OPENGL', 'OPENGLBLIT', 'PREALLOC', 'QUIT', 'RESIZABLE', 'RLEACCEL', 'RLEACCELOK', 'SCRAP_BMP', 'SCRAP_CLIPBOARD', 'SCRAP_PBM', 'SCRAP_PPM', 'SCRAP_SELECTION', 'SCRAP_TEXT', 'SRCALPHA', 'SRCCOLORKEY', 'SWSURFACE', 'SYSWMEVENT', 'TIMER_RESOLUTION', 'USEREVENT', 'USEREVENT_DROPFILE', 'UYVY_OVERLAY', 'VIDEOEXPOSE', 'VIDEORESIZE', 'YUY2_OVERLAY', 'YV12_OVERLAY', 'YVYU_OVERLAY', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__']
```

The code above is equipped with voluminous comments. As I have written it years and years ago starting on pygame and trying to understand sprites, the goal was to write it so clear that it will be easy to understand. Now you can judge yourself how successful I was with my style of self-explanatory variable naming and the provided explanations and informations.

Comment: I am not the downvoter - but (1) you didn't answer. (2) the part of your code to stop the program is rather confuse - not helping much; (3) you warn the OP should not try "advanced things like sprites" - when he is not using Pygame sprites at all. Any of these could get you a downvote

Comment: @jsbueno Thanks for response. Hmm ... (1) from my point of view I answered the question giving very good online resources on sprites and explaining short what is required to make them work (Group and class). To explain programming of sprites is in my opinion out of scope of what an answer is expected to provide. (2) I can't see any severe problem with stopping the program (3) from what I can "read" from OPs code about what was planned to achieve I can quite clearly see the intention of getting something self-made displayed on the screen and my code does it. Curios about OPs response.

Comment: The edit window plays TRICKS on me, not allowing to save my edits ... !!!